# Is it possible to add jQuery slider to come from the DB?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get the jQuery slider to come from the database to display it like its in HTML.

SLIDER IN HTML:  http://puu.sh/cCD3x/7421da5d3a.jpg

MY DATABASE: http://puu.sh/cCD5w/fe9465a903.png

This is my code for it:

```
<div class="slider_bg">
<div class="wrap">
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="slider">
    <!-- #camera_wrap_1 -->
    <div class="fluid_container">
        <div class="camera_wrap camera_azure_skin" id="camera_wrap_1">
            <div data-thumb="../images/thumbs/slider1.jpg" data-src="../images/slider/slider1.jpg">
            </div>
            <div data-thumb="../images/thumbs/slider2.jpg" data-src="../images/slider/slider2.jpg">
            </div>
            <div data-thumb="../images/thumbs/slider3.jpg" data-src="../images/slider/slider3.jpg">
            </div>
            <div data-thumb="../images/thumbs/slider4.jpg" data-src="../images/slider/slider4.jpg">
            </div>            
             </div><!-- #camera_wrap_1 -->
         <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- end #camera_wrap_1 -->
    <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

What I thought code work:

```
                                                                                        <?php
 $sql = "SELECT image FROM product where productID=2";
 $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error($connection));
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) //display the results
 {
 echo "<a href='../images/".$row['image']."'><img src='../images/".$row['image']."' /></a>"; 
 }
?>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?PHP
     $sql = "SELECT image FROM product where productID=2";
     $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error($connection));
?>  



<div class="slider_bg">
    <div class="wrap">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="slider">
        <!-- #camera_wrap_1 -->
        <div class="fluid_container">
            <div class="camera_wrap camera_azure_skin" id="camera_wrap_1">
                <?PHP while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)): //display the results ?>
                        <div data-thumb="../images/thumbs/<?PHP echo $row['image']; ?>" data-src="../images/slider/<?PHP echo $row['image']; ?>">
                         </div>
                <?PHP endwhile; ?>          

            </div><!-- #camera_wrap_1 -->
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
        <!-- end #camera_wrap_1 -->
        <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What do you mean? By the looks of your database, there is only one image which is having the productID as 2. Isn't that the image which is displayed?

Comment: Nothing is being displayed at all :s?

Comment: Okay, there can be two reasons to that. Either the image is not in your folder location, or the database query returns empty. Check if the the query results are empty using a var_dump inside the loop. If the query returns the correct image, then check if that image resides in your folder location..

Comment: Where do you suggest I put   <?php
$sql = "SELECT image FROM product where productID=2";
 $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error($connection));
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) //display the results
 {
 echo "<a href='../images/thumbs".$row['image']."'><img src='../images/".$row['image']."' /></a>"; 
 }

?>

Comment: Thanks for the help but how do I go about adding in the thumbs?